# Ionic w/ React Trigger Infinite Scroll until the page is filled

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have the following component.

```js
const Feed: React.FC<FeedProps> = memo((props) => {
    // ... lines skipped for brevity
    return (
        <div>
            <IonList>
                {
                    data.map((item) => {
                        return <FeedItem key={item.id!} item={item} />
                    })
                }
            </IonList>
            <IonInfiniteScroll onIonInfinite={(e: CustomEvent<void>) => __handleIonInfinite(e)}>
                <IonInfiniteScrollContent loadingText="Loading items" />
            </IonInfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    );

    async function __handleIonInfinite(e: CustomEvent<void>) {
        const result = await __get();
        if (result && result.length < environment.PAGE_SIZE) {
            (e.target as HTMLIonInfiniteScrollElement).disabled = true;
        }

        (e.target as HTMLIonInfiniteScrollElement).complete();
    }
});
```

Everything works fine when scrolling. I have one question though. At first, the page is empty and I need to scroll to trigger the event. I was wondering if there is a way of triggering the scroll event such that it fills the page?

I was thinking of implementing this myself but maybe it comes out of the box? Besides, it tends to be a little complex because, depending on your screen size, I would need to see how many times I should trigger this.